# Installing minpack.lm in R fails to compile

Tags: r, installation, r-package

I've tried to install minpack.lm a few times on two different ubuntu computers (one with anaconda's R shown below, the other with the system's R) and have not been able using the command

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> install.packages("minpack.lm")
```

I get a compilation error:

```
x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -I"/home/eddie/bin/anaconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -I/home/eddie/bin/anaconda3/include -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/eddie/bin/anaconda3/lib   -fpic  -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -I/home/eddie/bin/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda/- -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c nls_lm.c -o nls_lm.o
x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -I"/home/eddie/bin/anaconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -I/home/eddie/bin/anaconda3/include -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/eddie/bin/anaconda3/lib   -fpic  -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -I/home/eddie/bin/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda/- -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c prod.c -o prod.o
prod.c: In function 'matprod':
prod.c:55:41: error: expected ')' before 'FCONE'
        x, &nrx, y, &nry, &zero, z, &nrx FCONE FCONE);
                                         ^~~~~
prod.c: In function 'crossprod':
prod.c:67:37: error: expected ')' before 'FCONE'
    x, &nrx, y, &nry, &zero, z, &ncx FCONE FCONE);
                                     ^~~~~
make: *** [/home/eddie/bin/anaconda3/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:160: prod.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘minpack.lm’
* removing ‘/home/eddie/bin/anaconda3/lib/R/library/minpack.lm’
* restoring previous ‘/home/eddie/bin/anaconda3/lib/R/library/minpack.lm’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpQKYnHk/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("minpack.lm") :
  installation of package ‘minpack.lm’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any ideas what could be the cause/solution?

I tried resintalling R.

Comment: Since you seem to be using an anaconda version of R, try installing outside of R with `conda install -c r r-minpack.lm` [more info here](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/reference/packages/r-language-pkg-docs/)

Comment: Thank you! That let me use the script I was interested in.